# Please give examples and how to figure them out

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Give examples of (i) a set that is not a closed, bounded interval, but nevertheless contains its supremum and infimum, and (ii) a set that is not an open interval but nevertheless does not contain it supremum or infimum.
I've tried to look into the definition of open sets and closed sets.
There's a question which I've proved earlier 
Q. Show that a closed, bounded interval contains is supremum and infimum and that an open interval contains neither.
But I couldn't think of an example.

This is a question from Scharamm's book of Real Analysis.
Edit: I realised that not open sets don't mean closed sets.
P.S I'm a beginner in Analysis. Also I am new to stackexchange community.

Comment: Try not to just post questions, as people won't know where to start to be able to help you (and you will get downvotes, as happened here). Try to explain what you have tried and where and why you got stuck/need help. It would also help if you said where you found this question (week X of course Y, where we covered topic Z).

Comment: Thanks, I'm new. Will do that from next time.

Comment: You could, of course, edit your question...

Answer (score 1):

i.  Remove a point from a closed bounded interval.

ii.  A half open set.

Answer (score 1):

The Cantor set is not a closed bounded interval, yet contains its minimum (infimum) $0$ and maximum (supremum) $1$.

A set like $\{x \in \mathbb{Q}: x^2 < 2\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is not an open interval and does not contain its infimum $-\sqrt{2}$ and its supremum $\sqrt{2}$.